# postgresql recommended data type for money

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am building an app for estimate and invoicing. This app will be able to export or integrate with accounting software.

For PostgreSQL which data type would you recommend? and if NUMERIC, what do you recommend for precision & scale settings?

Comment: Use `numeric`.  The precision and scale depend on your application.  For many non-financial applications in US dollars, something like `(8, 2)` is usually fine.  But more scale and precision is fine.

Comment: The most typical case I've seen is `DECIMAL(12, 2)` but I've also seen some applications using 4 decimal places.

Comment: Whatever you choose: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm guessing you mean numeric(12,2). That is what I have decided to go with. Thx all

Comment: @virtualbis: `numeric(12,2)` and `decimal(12,2)` are exactly the same thing. `decimal` is an alias for `numeric`

Comment: Good to know. Thx @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 4):

numeric(12,2) it is then.

Thanks everyone. New to stackoverflow but loving it so far.